Fixed Header Containing Image and Hamburger Menu With Scrollable Content
This is what I am trying to do 
link
While I want the image 9 and the hamburger menu fixed and scroll the rest of the content.
I changed the position to fixed and the header is messed up.


This is my code:


#title_and_menu {
  position: fixed;
  /*was previously relative when the code worked*/
  width: 100%;
}

#myHeader {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}

#drop_menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 25px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#drop_menu>*{
  width: 35px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #c9c9c9;
  margin: 6px 0;
}
<body>
  <div id="title_and_menu">
    <div id="myHeader">
      <img src="https://ninepoint.cc/wp-content/themes/9pt2023/images/logo.svg" alt="home image" width="30" height="30">
    </div>
    <div id="drop_menu">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=”section1” style="background-color:#e2e2e2;width:100%">
    <h2 align="center" style="padding-top:200px;color:#767676">Heading</h2>
    <h1 align="center" style="color:#707070">Introduction</h1>
    <p style="margin-left:1em;margin-right:5em;padding-bottom:12.5em;color:#9f9f9f" align="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</body>




@Umesh Singh I edited the question. I am trying to fix the header image and hamburger menu and scroll the rest of the content.

@RUMBIDZAIMUKUNGUNUGWA I made a live snippet of your own code ... the header is already fixed and remains on top while scrolling the content.. so it's not clear which expectations aren't met

@DiegoD It is fixed but the hamburger menu is not displaying. I want it to show up as in the What I want to achieve image

By only using CSS you have two options. If you use position: fixed for the menu, you would need another relative positioned element that acts as a spacer. Place it at the very top of your DOM and set its height accordingly. Another way would be to set position: sticky and 'top: 0' to place the navigation element on top and keep it there. It will respect the following content until scrolled.

the hamburger placeholder is actually showing.. what you don't see are the menu options just because they are empty. But that's not related to what you stated as previously working with position: relative. You are missing the whole menu logic in your original code

@makkusu could you please post code for the spacer element. 











@makkusu that is what I did. I added a spacer div with position relative inside the fixed div but it's not helping

with a better inspection I got that you don't have an actualy placeholder for the hamburger icon but you actually styled 3 divs to achieve that similar result. that's why the misunderstanding. Those #hamburger_menuelements are not menu options! you gave the same id to different elements.. and that's invalid. You cannot. If you want to keep that strategy try using a class instead! Otherwise use an actual icon representing the menu like this https://fontawesome.com/icons/bars?s=solid

@DiegoD the second image 'What I am Getting' is all I see on the screen. No hamburger menu

and that's the origin of the misunderstanding.. because even if that html is not valid, it renders as expected on chrome (latest version) on desktop. Please try changing <div id="hamburger_menu"></div> to <div class="hamburger_menu"></div> and the style selector from #hamburger_menu to .hamburger_menu

@makkusu Could you please post code which does what you are suggesting

Is this what you are tying to achieve: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp ?

@DiegoD Instead of having a duplicate class hamburger_menu I used this instead #drop_menu>* Please see edit

This question is similar to: Fixed header, footer with scrollable content. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Barnee No The first image in my question shows what I am trying to achieve link

If you had just: top: 0; background: #fff; to your #title_and_menu in your css, it works no ? or I miss something

@VincentDecaux The logo 9. is in the right place but the hamburger menu is not showing

I was about to add this in comments but its so messed that's why adding in resposes. Issue is very simple to  fix, instead of position: fixed use position: sticky with top: 0 and it should be fixed.
Below is working example.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            height: 1002vh;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .mainDiv {
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: #1e1e1e;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        #title_and_menu {
            position: sticky;
            top:0;
            /*was previously relative when the code worked*/
            width: 100%;
        }

        #myHeader {
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: white;
        }

        #drop_menu {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            right: 25px;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #drop_menu>* {
            width: 35px;
            height: 1px;
            background-color: #c9c9c9;
            margin: 6px 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="title_and_menu">
            <div id="myHeader">
                <img src="https://ninepoint.cc/wp-content/themes/9pt2023/images/logo.svg" alt="home image" width="30" height="30">
            </div>
            <div id="drop_menu">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=”section1” style="background-color:#e2e2e2;width:100%">
            <h2 align="center" style="padding-top:200px;color:#767676">Heading</h2>
            <h1 align="center" style="color:#707070">Introduction</h1>
            <p style="margin-left:1em;margin-right:5em;padding-bottom:12.5em;color:#9f9f9f" align="center">Lorem ipsum
                dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat.</p>
        </div>

</body>

</html>




The content is jumping above the fixed header when I apply the styling

@RUMBIDZAIMUKUNGUNUGWA show it with image.

This is other code which is not posted in the question. @Meet
